# Breaking down "いんや, まだずらよ"?

Tags: meaning, role-language

I understand that `いんや, まだずらよ` means something along the lines of "No, not yet". At least, in the context I'm seeing it in (the question "Has Person A arrived yet?"). However, I'm having difficultly understanding how the parts of this give this meaning.

`まだ` I can see as being "Still"/"Yet". And the `よ` is surely just adding emphasis. But where are the `いんや` and `ずら` parts coming from? Do they have meaning on their own and how does that meaning come together to create the full sentence meaning above? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「いんや」 is an emphatic form of 「いや」 meaning "no". 　「いや」 is already an informal form of 「いいえ」.  I explained this 「ん」 [here](https://i2.wp.com/shiritaiwadai.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/koma_houritsu.png) recently.

「ずら」 is a [dictionary word](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%9A%E3%82%89-543774#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88) meaning 「だろう」.  Currently, it is used mainly around Nagano and Shizuoka.

> "Nope, not yet, I'd say."

Obviously, I do not know of the whole context these words appeared in, but it might be used as "role language" to indicate that the speaker is from the country side rather than as part of a real dialect.

Role language is extremely common in Japanese fiction and it is often incorrectly explained here as actual dialectal words and expressions from a particular area when the author's intention is just making a character sound "country" and/or old.

"Would that be O.K. legally?", says this character.

[image]

Comment: It is in a fictional setting, and I would guess you're correct that it is being used as role language in this case.